# Phrase similar filenames as a string with separated by coma and different filenames by whitespace

Tags: bash

I am trying to get a string from file names in a directory, grouping together with separated by coma and different file names separated by a single whitespace. Please see the Expected output in the end.

Files in the directory

```
usa_la2_sky_1.csv
usa_la2_sky_2.csv
usa_nyc1_sky_1.csv
usa_nyc1_sky_2.csv
```

I tried:

```sh
for f in *.csv ; do
    input=$input,$f
done
echo $input | sed s/,//
```

Output with my above code:

```
usa_la2_sky_1.csv,usa_la2_sky_2.csv,usa_nyc1_sky_1.csv,usa_nyc1_sky_2.csv
```

Expected output:

```
usa_la2_sky_1.csv,usa_la2_sky_2.csv usa_nyc1_sky_1.csv,usa_nyc1_sky_2.csv
```

Comment: How do you determine where to put the space?

Comment: Because this filenames string will be input to another tool which required filenames in such way.

Comment: I don't see a problem in your current output, it looks the same (to me) as you expected output. Is the problem that you have a leading `,` char in your current output? Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily, but you need to know what the `last` filename was. You can handle that by saving in a variable (originally set empty). Then just compare the initial part of the the filename for each with a simple *parameter expansion* (POSIX compliant), e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

last=                                       ## last originally empty
for i in *.csv; do                          ## loop over each file
    if [ -z "$last" ]; then                 ## if last empty, output file
        printf "%s" "$i"
    elif [ "$last" = "${i%_*}" ]; then      ## if last matches beginning of file
        printf ",%s" "$i"                   ## output comma and file
    else
        printf " %s" "$i"                   ## no match, output space and file
    fi
    last="${i%_*}"                          ## save beginning of filename in last
done
echo ""                                     ## tidy up with final newline
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your files in a sample directory, e.g.

```
$ tree .
.
├── usa_la2_sky_1.csv
├── usa_la2_sky_2.csv
├── usa_nyc1_sky_1.csv
└── usa_nyc1_sky_2.csv
```

Running the script produces:

```
$ bash myscript
usa_la2_sky_1.csv,usa_la2_sky_2.csv usa_nyc1_sky_1.csv,usa_nyc1_sky_2.csv
```

Where you have comma-separated similar filenames in groups separated by a space (which is what I understood you were asking for).

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
ls *.csv | awk '{key=$0;sub(/_[^_]*csv/,"",key);a[key]=(key in a)?a[key]","$0:$0} 
        END{for (i in a){print a[i]}}' | 
    paste -s -d ' '
```

We use ls to list all files ending in .csv. Then we use awk to group the files. We make the key by stripping out each _1.csv suffix. All these string are stored in an array and separated by ",". In the end we will print these. Since you wanted separate the group by space I used paste -s for this. This will paste each line in one line separated by a spaces indicated by -d ' '.

Comment: May I know what this *test_files* is?

Comment: How to assign this output string to a variable?

Comment: I am sorry. test_files was a leftover from testing, since I first read from a file with your files, instead of using ls *.csv and read from stdin. If you want to put it in a variable you can just wrap it in a subshell: `variable=$(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean pure Bash code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

shopt -s nullglob   # Globs that match nothing expand to nothing

input='' oldbase=''
for f in *.csv ; do
    base=${f%_*}
    [[ $base == "$oldbase" ]] && sep=, || sep=' '
    input+=${input:+$sep}$f
    oldbase=$base
done

printf '%s\n' "$input"
```

- `shopt -s nullglob` prevents the code trying to process a spurious (literal) `*.csv` file if there are no CSV files in the current directory.
- `base=${f%_*}` sets `$base` to the filename up to, but not including, the last `_` character in it.  (For example, `$base` for `usa_la2_sky_1.csv` is `usa_la2_sky`.)  See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string).
- `input+=${input:+$sep}$f` appends the current filename, possibly preceded by a separator, to the current `input` string.  `${input:+$sep}` expands to nothing if `$input` is empty, and to the value of `$sep` otherwise.  The effect of this is to have no separator at the start of `$input`.  See the "Use an alternate value" section in [Parameter expansion [Bash Hackers Wiki]](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).
  Another option is to simply always add the separator (`input+=$sep$f`) and remove the leading separator afterwards.  One way to remove the leading separator is `input=${input#?}`.